# How to find what the boundary of a quotient space looks like

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm reading Kosniowski's A first course in algebraic topology. In chapter 25 he discusses the fundamental group of some quotient spaces using Van Kampen theorem. I'm having troubles understanding how the boundaries of the following quotient spaces in figure 25.7 become the spaces in figure 25.9 after the identifications are made.

[image]

[image]

Since he doesn't explain any process to visualize the transformations under the identifications i'm guessing he's doing it by eye.

I've been able to handle simpler cases like the boundary of the torus becoming $\mathbb{S}^1 \lor \mathbb{S}^1$ after the identification, but not these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the  purpose of the triangles inside the hexagons. What happens if you identify the oriented edges denoted by $a_1,a_2, a_3$?

Let us first look at the vertices which we denote by $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_5$ beginning at the top and going clockwise (that is, $v_i$ corresponds to $2i$ o'clock am).

In the first picture the $a_1$-egdes begin at the vertices $v_0, v_2, v_4, v_5$ and end at the vertices $v_0, v_1, v_3$. Hence $v_0, v_2, v_4, v_5$ are mapped to a common point $w$ in the quotient space and $v_0, v_1, v_3$ are mapped to a common point $w'$ in the quotient space. Since $v_0$ occurs in both groups of points , we have $w = w'$. Hence the quotient space is obtained by attaching two loops denoted by $a_1, a_2$ to $w$.

Im am sure you can do the other two cases by yourself.

Comment: Why didn't you need to use the identifications of the $a_2$ edges to give the description of the space? Also, does  this method tell us the direction in which the loops $a_1$ and $a_2$ are traversed?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the first example it is already clear after considering only $a_1$ that all $v_i$ are  mapped to a single $w$. There is no need to consider $a_2$ for this conclusion. This is diiferent in the other two cases; you must consider all $a_i$ to see what happens to the vertices. There is no "real" direction in which $a_1, a_2$ are traversed in the quotient space - they are closed loops beginning and ending at $w$. It only seems that directions play a role if you look at the embeding into the plane. However, if you reverse one or two arrows, you will see that the resulting spaces are homeomorphic.